# How to get UserName and Password from a WCF basic request

Tags: wcf, basic-authentication, credentials

I have a Service which expose some functionality in Basic Auth to expose some feeds to powerpivot.

During the method call I can see (for example with fiddler) the credential under the attribute:

Authorization Basic Base64[MyLogin:MyPWD]

How can I get this data inside the web service?

I tried with:

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 foreach (var v in OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.Headers)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(v.Name);
        }
 foreach (var v in OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(v.Name + v.Actor);
        }
```

But string builder contains only ToTo like headers are only the To Header..

How can I obtain that data?

THank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
string header = WebOperationContext
                  .Current
                     .IncomingRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization];
```